# MetaMask - RPC Error: Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload

Tags: web3js, metamask

I have created a DApp. In all my functions where I have used send() function of web3, I am facing above error.

I have a function in which I used call() and it worked fine but all send() using functions are failing with above error.

I have seen all possible answers online but no help, can someone please help me? I have very quick submission please

Moreover, the read functions are working fine on DAPP, so Im sure contract is initialized correctly and contract functions works fine as well without Dapp, so metamask is correct too.

web3 version in DApp = 1.0
Please someone help.

This is my failing transaction:

```
Contract.methods.AuctionInfo(deadline, maxBids).send({from: accounts[0], gas: '21000', value: (0.1*maxBids) * 1000000000000000000}, (error, result) => {
                    if (result) console.log(result);
                    if (error) console.log(error);
                });
```

Comment: Do you have the full source? Are you sure you are using web v0.20? `.methods` and `.send` are from v1.0. Also gas 21000 is too low and to calculate value it is better to use BigNumber.

Comment: sorry, v1.0. I have edited the question with it. You need complete app.js?

Comment: Increasing the gas price to 210000 worked. Thanks.

Comment: `1000000000000000000 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

Comment: Change `(0.1*maxBids) * 1000000000000000000` to `\`${maxBids}e17\``.

Answer (score 1):

The comment-section indicates that your problem is solved.

Nevertheless, note that `1000000000000000000` is larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

So the expression `(0.1*maxBids) * 1000000000000000000` may yield an inaccurate value.

Therefore, assuming that the type of `maxBids` is `Number`, I recommend that you change it to:

```
`${maxBids}e17`
```

If `maxBids == 12.34`, for example, then the expression above will evaluate to the string `"12.34e17"`.

And when you pass this string to your contract-function call, web3 will convert it to a `BN` instance which represents the integer value of `1234000000000000000` (`1234` followed by 15 zeros).

Alternatively, since you are attempting to multiply `0.1*maxBids` by `10 ** 18`, you can simply use:

```
Web3.utils.toWei(0.1*maxBids)
```